# Front center mapped as LFE, LFE as front center on my 5.1 Debian 12

Tags: debian, audio, configuration, pulseaudio

switched from windows to linux yesterday after 10yrs

Trying to learn linux and it's damn hard just to do normal things my poor 3 brain cells . I literally can say I'm going insane.

Build: Intel i3 530,DH55TC MB no graphic/sound card. OS Debian 12| PulseAudio 16.1

Mapped my line in ,line out, Mic from pc to 5.1 surround speakers connected via 3 analog cables.I used this guide https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc/8ff198a5ac3f0050f68795233c4866d0. Thank you

All front-left,Front-right,Rear-left,Rear-right all working mapped correctly but my front_center mapped to LFE, LFE vice versa. when I press front-center it's coming out subwoofer and front-center giving static when test.I literally have tried diff channel orders in default.pa & daemon.conf but nothing worked.

What changes I have done till now ?

~/.config/pulse/default.pa  #add this line **set this as my default sink & source**

> load-module module-combine-sink channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe

~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf  #add this line

> remixing-produce-lfe = yes
> remixing-consume-lfe = yes
> lfe-crossover-freq = 80
> default-sample-channels = 6

/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/

```
Mapping analog-surround-51] device-strings = surround51:%f 
channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe ##changed only this line##
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-lineout analog-output-speaker 
priority = 13 
direction = output
```

**My pactl info**

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 5
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: yamihero777
Host Name: !NotPC
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 16.1
Default Sample Specification: s16le 6ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-left-of-center,front-center,front-right,front-right-of-center,rear-center
Default Sink: combined
Default Source: combined.monitor
Cookie: ead8:d297
```

I really don't understand why Default channel map entirely different. I tried to uncomment

> Default Channel map in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf but still issue didn't fix and Pactl info showed the same even after a reboot.

In win 11[diff ssd not dual boot] it's working so can't say hwd issue. Kindly help to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps for someone.

- First make sure copy `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` & `default.pa` files to `~/.config/pulse` folder
- go to `daemon.conf` in `config/pulse` folder, uncomment only default channel map and set it as following

  - for 5.1: `front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe`
  - for 7.1: `front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe,side-left,side-right`
- No changes need to be done in `default.pa`, just leave as it is.
- Type in terminal

  ```shell
  killall pulseaudio
  ```

  It will restart. If not, type

  ```shell
  pulseaudio --start
  ```
- Now type in terminal

  ```
  pactl info
  ```

  What you see ,that read by system until this corrected nothing will change

  - default sample channel should be whatever your sound system is
  - default channel map should match with map we set in daemon.conf file in config folder
  - type `pacmd list-sinks`, select which makes senses to you and by using `set-default-sink` command set it default. Same goes for sources too .
  - reboot pc and should see you sound system profile (ex: Analog Output 5.1) in pulseaudio control and control center
  - test in control center. All should be fine. If `pactl info` shows all good but still facing issues like channels routed wrong you need to change cables on the speaker and test it.

After 1 week of trail and error, my sound system up and I got excellent knowledge. Double win. Cheers!